# ogr2ogr : Converting KML to GeoJson

Tags: gdal, geojson, kml, ogr2ogr

I have a requirement to convert .KML file to GeoJSON or JSON. Can you please recommend open source command line tools on GNU/Linux(2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64)? I have installed gdal, when I run..

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" geojson.json Areas.kml
```

I get this error :-

> Unable to open datasource `Areas.kml' with the following drivers.   ->
>   ESRI Shapefile   -> MapInfo File   -> UK .NTF   -> SDTS   -> TIGER  -> S57   -> DGN   -> VRT   -> REC   -> Memory   -> BNA   -> CSV   -> GML   -> GPX   -> KML   -> GeoJSON   -> GMT   -> AVCBin

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  You have included a `qgis` tag but make no mention of it in your Question body or title.  If it is not part of the specific workflow you are asking about here then I recommend that you edit your Question to remove it.

Answer (score 12):

The correct syntax is:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON geojson.json Areas.kml
```

You can also use [togeojson](https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson) ([Online Maps moving forward, from KML to GeoJSON](http://paazmaya.com/online-maps-moving-forward-from-kml-to-geojson))

```
togeojson Areas.kml > geojson.json
```

Comment: Thanks. togeojson worked. Do we have any open source tools to convert hml to esrijson or geojson to esrijason? Thanks Again.

Comment: [esri_to_geojson.py](https://github.com/odoe/SpatialJSON/blob/master/utils/esri_to_geo.py) and [geo_to_esri.py](https://github.com/odoe/SpatialJSON/blob/master/utils/geo_to_esri.py) for example

Comment: The original ogr2ogr syntax was also correct. Using "GeoJSON" is OK, and sometimes the syntax is compulsory, like -f "ESRI Shapefile". Next time, tell the GDAL version and try to share a sample from the failing data.